# Saving output from biodiversityR

Tags: r, export

I am trying to figure out how to save output from a biodiversityR analysis.  for example:

```
check.datasets(dune, dune.env)
dist.eval(dune,'euclidean')
Ordination.model1 <- rda(dune ~ Management,dune.env)
check.ordiscores(dune,Ordination.model1, check.species=T)
summary(Ordination.model1, scaling=1)
```

I want to save summary(Ordination.model1, scaling=1) in a readable format.

So far, I have tried

```
out<-capture.output(summary(Ordination.model1, scaling=1))
write.csv(out, file="Documents/Rstuff/Sequence analysis/dunetest.csv")
```

But this gives me a file in which the columns are not correctly separated.

```
cat(out, "Dunesummaryoutput.txt")
```

also gives me a jumble without the correct separation.

Any help is much appreciated! I want to move on to a much bigger dataset, for which the output actually maxes out the R screen, so I need to be able to save it to view it.

Comment: Take a look at `?sink` which essentially creates a log file. Remember to use `dev.off()` when finished outputting your results.

Comment: Thank you!  That worked perfectly.